# Issue with including p-value stars using sjPlot tab_model

Tags: r, sjplot

I am plotting the results of multiple regressions in R using `tab_model` from `sjPlot`. The regression results are produced, however, I am now trying to add simultaneous displays of the numeric p-values and their corresponding stars for significance. By default the plot only renders the numeric values, so I added the term `p.style = "scientific_stars"`. This generated the following error:

```
Warning: Could not access model information.Error in fam.info$is_linear || identical(fam.info$link_function, "identity") : 
  invalid 'x' type in 'x || y'
```

Unfortunately, due to the nature of the data, I cannot provide the exact data I am working with. However, the models are both basic OLS models produced using the `lm` function. The two models have the exact same variables, and number of observations.
The code for the function is the following:

```
tab_model(model_1, model_2, auto.label = TRUE, show.se = TRUE, show.ci = FALSE, show, p.style = "scientific_stars")
```

I have tried plotting a signle model, and chainging the other labels, but the same error is generated.

Is there anyway to fix this problem and include both the numeric values and the stars in the rendering?

Comment: There's an extra `show,` between `show.ci` and `p.style`. Remove it and your code should run fine.

Comment: @jrcalabrese You're right, such an obvious mistake on my part. Thank you very much!